# java number and "*" looped patterns

Tags: java, loops, design-patterns, for-loop, logic

The two patterns I'm trying to obtain are:

```
11111
12222
12333
12344
12345
```

and...

```
*1234
**123
***12
****1
*****
```

Please help me on this. I can't find a way.

The only code I can think of is:

```
public class pattern_5
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n=5;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {        
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {        
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }        
    }
}
```

The output is wrong. Basically, I only get half of the intended figure (you can get the star half by changing j to * maybe).

Comment: Please format you code so it s readable...

Comment: Well, it does show up perfectly on my PC. Don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Scenario

```
int n=5;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {        
            for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {   
                if(i<j) {     
                   System.out.print(i);
                } else {     
                   System.out.print(j);
                } 
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }
```

Output:

```
11111
12222
12333
12344
12345
```

And for second scenario:

```
int n=5;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {        
            for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {   
                if(i<j) {     
                   System.out.print(j-i);
                } else {     
                   System.out.print("*");
                } 
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }
```

Output:

```
*1234
**123
***12
****1
*****
```

Comment: This works, I guess, I'll be able to work out the alternate one too.

Comment: The second one doesn't work according to this code. 
Changing the i to *:
`1****
12***
123**
1234*
12345
`
And after changing j to *:
`*1111
**222
***33
****4
*****
`

Comment: It is working for me. I think you made some mistake in that. can you please check once

Answer (score 0):

For the first scenario

```
11111
12222
12333
12344
12345
```

you can do is

```
int n=5;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{        
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {   
        if(j<i) {     
           System.out.print(j);
        } else {     
           System.out.print(i);
        } 
    }
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

Apply the same logic for the * part I think you would be able to guess it by now how it would work

Comment: Your "j" and "i" are interchanged ans thus I got a new pattern.

Comment: I'm trying to get the second one with the stars. It doesn't work by changing the j and i to * in the if-else block.